# What is the difference of calculating signal power that using these two methods: using moving average filter and using forgetting factor?

Tags: signal-power, real-time, moving-average, acoustics

The conventional signal power calculation can be:

$$
P(n) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}x^2(n-i)
$$

$x(n)$ is the signal. However, I have seen another method:

$$
P(n) = \lambda P(n-1) + (1-\lambda) x^2(n)
$$
Here, $\lambda$ is the forgetting factor. So what is the difference between these two methods? Which one is widely used in real-time process? Which one is more computationally efficient?

Answer (score 2):

> So what is the difference between these two methods?

They are different types of lowpass filters. There are many other choices as well.

> Which one is widely used in real-time process?

You'll probably find the IIR lowpass more frequently than a moving average filters. Moving average isn't a great lowpass filter since it has a lot of side lobes in the frequency domain.

In general, people use a lowpass filter that's the best choice for the requirements of their specific application. For example, if you calculate the power for a sound pressure level meter, there are standards for different time constants, which in turn determines the choice of lowpass filter.

> Which one is more computationally efficient?

In almost all cases the IIR version will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

They both square the input going in, $x^2[n]$.

They both filter $x^2[n]$ with a low-pass filter having gain at DC equal to 1 (or 0 dB).  So the intent is to get the DC value of $x^2[n]$ and to not scale that DC value.

The impulse response of the two low-pass filters are different.